# Emscripten: Passing struct pointer as Argument

Tags: javascript, malloc, emscripten

I want to allocate a struct for emscripten and pass it to a function using a ccall.
The c struct looks like this:

```
typedef  float HPDF_REAL;
typedef  struct  _HPDF_Point {
  HPDF_REAL  x;
  HPDF_REAL  y;
} HPDF_Point;
```

So I allocate two floats in Javascript and pass it as an argument

```
struct_ptr = Module['allocate']([123,321], 'float', ALLOC_NORMAL)
res = Module['ccall']('HPDF_Page_GetCurrentTextPos', 'number', ['number', 'number'], [page_ptr, struct_ptr])
```

But when I get the resulting struct data

```
FLOAT_SIZE = 4
point = {
  x: getValue(struct_ptr, 'float')
  y: getValue(struct_ptr+FLOAT_SIZE, 'float')
}
```

my allocated memory was not touched and still `point.x==123` and `point.y==321`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm just using the values `123` and `321` as dummy initializations to check whether the memory was 'touched'. Using zeros also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, allocate() is an internal function - as the docs say (see comment right above the function definition), it is tricky to use and not recommended. Instead, better to just use _malloc to allocate some space, and use setValue to write to it.

Second, make sure your C function takes the structure as a pointer and not a reference (which C++ can do). Paste the function here (original C and compiled JS) so we can help you, or add debug statements inside it to see what is happening.